# Facebook chat webhook is no longer sending a JSON with the senders text - just their ID

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I developed a very simple chat-bot for Facebook, where I saved the JSON file that Facebook sends into a new file, fb.txt. In this JSON one of the fields in the messaging array was the text that was sent from Facebook, but that no longer seems the case.

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['hub_challenge'])) {
    $challenge = $_REQUEST['hub_challenge'];
    $token = $_REQUEST['hub_verify_token'];
}

if($token == "macross93") {
    echo $challenge;
}

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$userID = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];

$message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];

echo $userID." and ".$message;
file_put_contents("fb.txt", file_get_contents($userID));

$access_token="EAAElJTd6foABAGhCjYcL3ikrPMFkOZBihqb5jzVZCuCnJd8oL4jFZAZCV26EYiOXGLzkz6lKZAMDXBKDsFwWFVYBVfSguV2ZCZCgGNCOLCxWWHQYC8of3DJks4AmEAVFo2DB29TajZBGQDUYtQqOWaig3M2m5ioeOElY7CPXZB3eEgAZDZD";

$url="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/messages?access_token=EAAElJTd6foABAGhCjYcL3ikrPMFkOZBihqb5jzVZCuCnJd8oL4jFZAZCV26EYiOXGLzkz6lKZAMDXBKDsFwWFVYBVfSguV2ZCZCgGNCOLCxWWHQYC8of3DJks4AmEAVFo2DB29TajZBGQDUYtQqOWaig3M2m5ioeOElY7CPXZB3eEgAZDZD";

$jsonData = "{
    'recipient': {
    'id': $userID
    },
    'message': {
        'text': 'finally, the bait is over'
    }
}";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);

if(!empty($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message'])) {
    curl_exec($ch);
}
```

And the JSON I receive now is:

```json
{
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [{
        "id": "632423650282074",
        "time": 1489785206037,
        "messaging": [{
            "sender": {
                "id": "892399990863615"
            },
            "recipient": {
                "id": "632423650282074"
            },
            "timestamp": 1489785206027,
            "read": {
                "watermark": 1489785205361,
                "seq": 0
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

Any ideas how to read the message like I used to be able to?

Answer (score 1):

That JSON response corresponds to the **read** event callback payload from Facebook when a user reads your message. See the [documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message-read).

What you are interested in is the [**message** callback](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message). Check your webhook setup to make sure you are subscribed to the **messages** event callback.

[image: webhook event subscription]